# timestamp string split to get date and time effective way

Tags: java, regex, string, split

1) using regular expressions, patterns

2) using split function in String class

I tried using split function i think its not a good coding practice.
splitted input string using '_' iterate array like that

Strings

```
  START_READING_20140723_093539.jpg
  Description_20140723_093539.jpg
  Qunantity_20140723_183539.jpg
  END_READING_20140723_093539.jpg
```

Input Format is : `yyyyMMdd_HHmmss`

Output Format is : `23-07-2014 6:35:39PM`

Comment: oK.I got your matter. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP doesn't show any effort.

Comment: String s[] = input.split('_'); like this then SimpleDateFormat parse and format methods

Answer (score 2):

For any input string from the statement, consider for instance

```
"START_READING_20140723_093539.jpg".split("\\.|_")
```

which yields

```
Array("START", "READING", "20140723", "093539", "jpg")
```

Get the second and third last items, and then as suggested apply `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html) for the whole thing?

```
import joda.time.format.*;
import joda.time.*;

DateTimeFormatter inputFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd'_'HHmmss");
LocalDateTime timestamp = inputFormat.parseLocalDateTime(theString);

DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd'-'MM'-'yyyy' 'hh':'mm':'ssa");
String output = outputFormat.print(timestamp);
```

If you're using Java 8 you should use the java.time package instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
     import re
     pattern=re.compile(r".*?(\d+)_(\d+).jpg")
     print pattern.match(x).groups()
```

This will give you the date and time.Then you can use mktime or some other utility in python to get it in format you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
 String str = "START_READING_20140723_093539.jpg";
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.')));
 scanner.useDelimiter("[^\\p{Alnum},\\.-]");
 String[] arr=new String[2];
 int i=0;
 while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            arr[i]=scanner.next();
            i++;
     } else {
             scanner.next();
      }
    }
 String dateStr=arr[0]+"_"+arr[1];
 DateFormat df1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
 DateFormat df2=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ssa");
 System.out.println(df2.format(df1.parse(dateStr)));
```

Out put:

```
  23-07-2014 09:35:39AM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DateFormat to parse the input to a java.util.Date or Calendar and format it to String using a second DateFormat with your wanted output format.